# create database in postgresql with bash command

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, ubuntu, psql

Im trying to create a database in postgresql using linux.
I connected to postgres with

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres 
postgres=# then i tried **CREATE DATABASE demo** or **createdb demo**
```

but none of them worked when i checked with **\l** command.
Any help ?

Comment: What did you get as result of your CREATE DATABSE demo; ? You should have the message like : CREATE DATABASE and that's it ... so what said PostgreSQL ?

Comment: i got nothing...after i added quotes it created but i can't drop database now (just for testing)

Comment: You can't drop a database when you are connected to it ... but the command is simply DROP DATABASE demo; when you are corrected to postgres default database.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot the semicolon

Answer (score 12):

`sudo su - postgres` to become postgres

then `psql -c "create database demo"` to create it from shell

Comment: i added quotes it is worked but i can't drop database demo now :/ 5 (to test it)

Answer (score 4):

first:

```
    sudo su postgres
```

and then enter your password
then type:

```
     psql
```

and type this command:

```
    CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

Comment: Or simply start `psql -U postgres ...`

Answer (score 2):

simple type on bash

$ `createdb -U postgres(db user) dbname`

if set hba_config in pg for access to db  in network type

$ `createdb -h YOUR_IP -U postgres(db user) dbname`

if you set password for db user pg ask your password to create database